# Необходим SQL запрос

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос

На данный момент освежаю свои знания SQL, запрос должен удалить из таблицы cities=(date, city.name, temperature) с РК (date, city.name) два последних измерения температуры для каждого города. Подскажите куда копать, или как ориентировочно должен выглядеть запрос.

Answer (score 0):

я дополню ответ от [@versetty777](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/533449/versetty777)

Один из способов сделать это - использовать запрос DELETE с подзапросом, который возвращает две последние записи для каждого города по дате.

```
DELETE FROM cities
WHERE (date, city.name) IN 
  (SELECT date, city.name
  FROM cities
  GROUP BY city.name
  ORDER BY date DESC
  LIMIT 2)
```

В данном запросе мы группируем строки по имени города и сортируем их по дате в обратном порядке, затем выбираем последние 2 записи для каждого города с помощью ключевого слова LIMIT 2. Затем мы используем этот подзапрос в качестве условия для запроса DELETE, чтобы удалить соответствующие записи из таблицы cities.

Однако, этот запрос может быть не эффективен для больших таблиц и может привести к большой нагрузке на базу данных. Поэтому в зависимости от размера таблицы и количества записей может быть лучше использовать другой метод удаления данных, например, с использованием индексов или с помощью хранимых процедур или триггеров.